# HornetQ XA not participating in bitronix transaction with Spring Boot

Tags: jboss7.x, spring-boot, hornetq, spring-jms, bitronix

I'm trying to connect to a HornetQ JMS server running in JBoss 7.1.1 from a standalone Spring Boot application. I can get to the server and push messages to the queue with a configuration like this:

```
<bean name="hornetConnectionFactory" class="org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQXAConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="ha" type="boolean" value="false" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration">
            <constructor-arg value="org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory" />
            <constructor-arg>
                <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Object">
                    <entry key="host" value="127.0.0.1" />
                    <entry key="port" value="5445"></entry>
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultDestination" class="org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQQueue">
    <constructor-arg index="0"
        value="outgoingMessageQueue"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userCredsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="hornetConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jms.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jms.password}"/>     
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory" primary="true">
    <constructor-arg ref="userCredsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="20"/>
</bean>

<bean name="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"
    p:connectionFactory-ref="jmsConnectionFactory"
    p:defaultDestination-ref="defaultDestination" />
```

However the XA connection is not participating in JTA transaction that I have enabled through Spring Boot's bitronix support. The database connection is using JTA. How do I get Spring Boot to get this JMS connection to enlist as a XA resource in its transaction manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work now. It was simplier than I thought - I was able to get Spring Boot to connect to JBoss's HornetQ with this in the application.properties:

```
spring.hornetq.mode=native
spring.hornetq.host=127.0.0.1
spring.hornetq.port=5445

spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.user=user
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.password=password
```

And the jmsTemplate picked up the XA JmsConnection automatically. All the earlier XML is not apparently necessary under Boot.